# I get low disk space warning after my last upgrade

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, disk-usage, cinnamon

I am using Linux mint 16 cinnamon. After my last upgrade free disk space dropped from 4.2GB to around 344MB. Don't know what happened. This is the output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda10       10G  9.1G  329M  97% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.7G  4.0K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           345M  1.4M  344M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.7G  1.3M  1.7G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user
```

How can I clear all the temporary files and folders.

Contents of var/log/dpkg.log for last upgrade are here: [dpkg.log](http://ur1.ca/h5xq4)

Comment: Start by finding out what directory is taking up all your space by running $ sudo du -h / --max-depth=1 then start drilling down from there

Answer (score 3):

The files in `/tmp` *should* be removed automatically at every reboot.

Finding the culprit is usually a process that takes several steps.

I suggest you start with

```
du -sh /*
```

to get a list of the directories in `/` with their size (`-s`: sum up, `-h`: human readable)

Then you descend into the biggest directory and repeat.

```
du -sh /var/*
```

and so on. (`/var` contains `/var/log` which can get quite big)

If there are more than a few subdirectories in one directory the visual comparison becomes difficult. In this case use something like

```
du -s /usr/* | sort -nr
```

to get the biggest directories at the end of the output (size not as nicely readable as with `-h`)

Comment: FWIW the `ncdu` command is designed to more or less automating this `du -sh *` process for the user. Also, it doesn't look like `/tmp` is mounted as `tmpfs` so I don't think a reboot would've cleared it.

Comment: @JoelDavis that's a nice tool I didn't know about!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some temporary package files leftover. If they are not cleared by a reboot, or if you do not want to reboot, you can use a cleanup utility such as [bleachbit](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/bleachbit).

Or you can use generic disk-usage tools (disktree, treefolders, ...) or `du -sk` manually as guntbert suggested. Only be careful about what you delete, of course.